# Get Google Calendar and Events using Google service account

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I want to get user's Google calendar list and events using Google service account.

I am trying this using CalendarService, but i couldn't find the solution.

My Code:

```
         string path = KeyPath;
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(
            path,
            "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        var provider = new AssertionFlowClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, certificate)
        {
            ServiceAccountId = "XXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
            Scope = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full"


        };
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<AssertionFlowClient>(provider, AssertionFlowClient.GetState);


        var cService = new CalendarService(auth);
```

It shows error Calendarservice has some invalid arguments. I don't know how to handle this service. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to share the existing calendar with the service account

```
<paste-your-account-here>@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

(You can find the account in question under the credentials tab in Google Developers Console, it's called 'EMAIL ADDRESS')